# ng-click not working - TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, semantic-ui

I am using semantic UI to format my website with AngularJS. My controller is set up and works well. But it just doesn't like this part of my code:

```
    <div class="ui piled feed segment">
        <h2 class="ui header">
            Comments
        </h2>
        <div class="event" ng-repeat = "comment in comments | reverse">
            <div class="ui green horizontal label">
                {{comment.user}}
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="summary" ng-click="doSomething()">
                    {{ comment.content }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the AngularJS code:

```
$scope.doSomething = function(){
    alert('blah');
};
```

Basically, I want to execute doSomething() when the content is clicked. But for some reason it is not working and gives the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/js/lib/angular.min.js:65:98
    at http://localhost:3000/js/lib/angular.min.js:72:222
    at http://localhost:3000/js/lib/angular.min.js:144:140
    at Object.e.$eval (http://localhost:3000/js/lib/angular.min.js:88:347)
    at Object.e.$apply (http://localhost:3000/js/lib/angular.min.js:88:454)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/js/lib/angular.min.js:144:122)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.n.event.dispatch (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:3:8066)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:3:4774)
```

I am quite unsure what this error means because usually "undefined" means there is something wrong with the function definition but here I spot nothing wrong. I have ng-click inside ng-repeat else where in this app and it works fine. Is it because of semantic UI?

Comment: it wont like this, first you have to assign ng-app in your html

Comment: Oh, that is only a snippet of my code. The app, module, controller, everything is well defined.

Comment: can you plz post a fiddle demo.

Comment: do you have your function defined inside a controller, and the `ng-controller` inside your `<body>` tag?

Comment: So the html code above is in a partial file. Basically, I have an app with a router. When a tab is clicked, the user will be redirected to the partial url and a controller is responsible for that.

angular.module('flavor', ['flavorServices', 'firebase'])
.config(flavorRouter);
function flavorRouter ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
 .when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/some.html',
  controller: 'someCtrl'});
}

Comment: And the html code above is in that partials/some.html. Actually, I have ng-click in ng-repeat in the same file and it works perfectly. But just this one, it won't work. I am thinking maybe it is because of the Semantic UI module that I use here.

Comment: I fixed this problem. It seems to be that I am using the older version of angularJS that is causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="ui piled feed segment" ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
            <div class="summary" ng-click="doSomething()">
                {{name}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        app.controller('myController',function($scope){
            $scope.name = "Hi I am a new user Click me!";
            $scope.doSomething = function(){
                alert('blah');
                $scope.msg = 'clicked';
            };
        })
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with calling it from inside of an ng-repeat. I forgot the details, but it's some sort of scoping issue.

instead of $scope.doSomething, try

```
$scope.myObject = {};
$scope.myObject.doSomething = function(){//stuff};
```

then in the HTML call myObject.doSomething();

Then if I'm right about my assumption and that actually works, you may want to check out this article on angular practices that helps avoid this type of scoping issue.

http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html